# Fill backgroundless Image of letter with Image

Tags: html, css

I would like this fill the "E" image with the image of the stack of books. I have no idea how to achieve this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you forgot to add your efforts in trying to solve this problem. Please read [how-to-ask-good-question-on-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I edited the 'E' image asset you were using so that the E was actually transparent and the background was white. Then if you add a background image to the img element you'll get the desired effect. Turn the 'E' image asset background into whatever color you're wanting.

```css
img {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLmuY.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/0GoQbb4.png" />
```

Another way to get the desired effect would be to edit the image assets themselves. This would allow you to keep the 'E' image asset background transparent.

Comment: Hi Nick! Thank you for you solution. I would need the background to stay transparent, so I am curious about how I would edit the image assets themselves to reach this effect? Also, I forgot to mention, I want the E to be filled with the book image when I hover over it.

Comment: I would suggest using the image you already have and making another with the books inside the E (you can use Photoshop or a photo editing tool to accomplish this) and then  replace the image with a hover selector.